# WPF user control binding dynamic combobox

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a select list called Printers which is filled by default, after selecting a value from this select list the list called Trays should be filled but it doesn't. I've tried various methods but it seems to me that I still don't understand what the problem is. In addition, I would like to see a new list after pressing the Add next row button and it would also be full. I tried to use DependencyProperty and INotifyPropertyChanged but I don't think I fully understand the basics of the assumption or my problem is specific.

[image: App]

```
<UserControl x:Class="TestWPF.User_Controls.TrayItem"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF.User_Controls"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         Name="ucTray"
         d:DesignHeight="450" d:DesignWidth="800">
<Grid Background="White">
    <StackPanel Margin="10" x:Name="spTray" Orientation ="Horizontal" Height="35" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Trays</Label>
        <ComboBox  Width="250" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=ucTray, Path=Trays }" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
        <Label VerticalAlignment="Center">Documents</Label>
        <ComboBox Width="250" VerticalContentAlignment="Center">
            <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Documents , RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=UserControl}}" />
                </DataTemplate>
            </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ComboBox>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

```
namespace TestWPF.User_Controls
{
  
    public partial class TrayItem : UserControl
    {


        public List<string> Trays
        {
            get { return (List<string>)GetValue(TraysProperty); }
            set { SetValue(TraysProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Trays.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty TraysProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Trays", typeof(List<string>), typeof(TrayItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));



        public List<string> Documents
        {
            get { return (List<string>)GetValue(DocumentsProperty); }
            set { SetValue(DocumentsProperty, value); }
        }

        // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Documents.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
        public static readonly DependencyProperty DocumentsProperty =
            DependencyProperty.Register("Documents", typeof(List<string>), typeof(TrayItem), new PropertyMetadata(null));

     

        public TrayItem()
        {           
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

```
<Window x:Class="TestWPF.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TestWPF"
        xmlns:control="clr-namespace:TestWPF.User_Controls"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <StackPanel Margin="10" x:Name="spItems">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Label>Printers</Label>
                <ComboBox x:Name="cmbPrinterList" Width="300" SelectionChanged="cmbPrinterList_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding MyPrinters}">
                    <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
                </ComboBox>
            </StackPanel>

            <control:TrayItem x:Name="cTray" Trays="{Binding MyTrays, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Documents="{Binding Path = MyDocuments, Mode=TwoWay}">

            </control:TrayItem>
        </StackPanel>
        <Button x:Name="btnAddTray" Margin="10" Width="100" Height="40" Click="btnAddTray_Click" >Add next row</Button>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

```
namespace TestWPF
{
    
    public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public List<string> MyPrinters { get; set; }

        public string? _SelectedPrinter;
        public string? SelectedPrinter
        {
            get
            {
                return _SelectedPrinter;
            }
            set
            {
                _SelectedPrinter = value;
            }
        }
        private List<string>? _MyTrays;
        public List<string>? MyTrays 
        { 
            get
            {
                return _MyTrays;
            }
            set 
            { 
                _MyTrays = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPrinter");
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyTrays");
                RaisePropertyChanged("MyDocuments");
            }
        }
        public List<string>? MyDocuments { get; set; }

        public MainWindow()
        {
           
            InitializeComponent();
            DataContext = this;

            MyPrinters = new List<string>()
            {
                "Printer_1",
                "Printer_2",
                "Printer_3"
            };
        }
        private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler? PropertyChanged;

        private void cmbPrinterList_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
         
            string? value = (string?)cmbPrinterList.SelectedItem;
            switch (value)
            {
                case "Printer_1":
                    MyTrays = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "aaa",
                        "bbb",
                        "ccc"
                    };
                    MyDocuments = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "zzz",
                        "qqq",
                        "rrr"
                    };
                    break;
                case "Printer_2":
                    MyTrays = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "111",
                        "222",
                        "333"
                    };
                    MyDocuments = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "666",
                        "777",
                        "888"
                    };
                    break;
                case "Printer_3":
                    MyTrays = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "1dg",
                        "b2f",
                        "bs4"
                    };
                    MyDocuments = new List<string>()
                    {
                        "b2vg",
                        "eb5",
                        "asc"
                    };
                    break;
            }
            SelectedPrinter = value;
        }

        private void btnAddTray_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
           
            TrayItem trayItem = new TrayItem { DataContext = cTray.DataContext };
            spItems.Children.Add(trayItem);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You probably wanted to bind the ItemsSource properties of the ComboBoxes instead of the Text properties of the TextBlocks in their ItemTemplates. The ItemTemplates seem to be redundant. In order to get the selected items from the ComboBoxes you would also need to bind their SelectedItem properties to properties of your control.

Comment: You're right, I just added the ItemSource and it worked. Now, however, there is a problem when we add a new row, the data in the select list is not populated.

Comment: After adding the new row, do you 'RaisePropertyChanged()` for the list?

Comment: Yes, the problem was that I did not set binding for the whole new row, now it works.